# Почему не создаётся файл в с++

Tags: c++

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
//FILE* file;
// file=fopen("D:\file.txt" , "w+");
ofstream WAVf;
WAVf.open("C:/newWAV.txt");
WAVf.close();
```

Не знаю почему но не создаётся файл. Писал ofstream WAVf("newWAV.txt")- результата нет, через fopen тоже нет. Переместил проект с флешки на комп и тоже нет. Пользуюсь С++ Builder 2009. Скажите плз что не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем дело было в том, что я создал проект с формой, а не просто консольный проект и написание void main() не имеет смысла. Когда код поместил в кнопку, то всё заработало.

Answer (score 3):

Да скорей всего просто прав у вашей программы для такого действия - писать в корень системного диска - недостаточно...

Comment: когда от админа запускаю тоже ничего не происходит

Comment: У меня при запуске от имени администратора создало пустой файл в корне C:. Попробуйте для начала на другом диске, что будет? Может, у вас C: - русская "С"? :)

Comment: Всё равно ничего нет

Comment: Последний вопрос - исходя из того, что у вас закомментарено `"D:\file.txt"` - у вас вот так написано, как показано? `"C:/newWAV.txt"`? Через **прямую** косую черту? И каким компилятором пользуетесь?

Comment: Неоч разбираюсь в компиляторах, но вроде bcc32 или brc32 или brcс32, ну вобщем то, что лежит в папке bin. Что насчёт того что закоментированно, это я по другому пытался(что не важно) и писал я по разному и вот так: "C:/newWAV.txt" и так: "C:\newWAV.txt" и так: "C:\newWAV.txt" и так: "C:\\newWAV.txt" и так: "newWAV.txt" - всё тоже самое

Comment: Тогда не понимаю. Если это весь код... А чему равно значение `errno` при попытке создания файла с помощью `fopen`?

Comment: Watch Name Value
fp [process not accessible], там в отладчике показывается строчка зелёным цветом, типо всё нормально прошло, но а так я незнаю